# Cannot create bitmap using canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

Would you mind helping me to solve this problem.

I want to draw a circle to a bitmap, and then draw bitmap to mapView.
But bitmap still not created.
Here is my code:

```
public class CustomOverlay extends Overlay {
    public HeatPoint pt;
    Context mContext;
    Bitmap bmp;
    public CustomOverlay(HeatPoint pt,Context context){
        this.pt=pt;  
        this.mContext = context;
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Paint gp = new Paint();

    gp.setColor(0xFF0000);

    gp.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    myCanvas.drawRect(10,10,40,40,gp);   

    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pt.getGeo(), screenPts);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x-16, screenPts.y-2, null);
        return true;
    }      

}
```

In this code, I want to draw a circle on screen, but when I run it, nothing happened.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you try changing gp.setColor(0xFF0000);--> gp.setColor(0xFFFF0000);?

Comment: are there any errors creating the Bitmap? If so: logcat please!

Answer (score 0):

You can see below code

```
int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;

BitmapConfig conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
```

This [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222194714/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/11/drawing-with-canvas-in-android-renewed.html) might help you